# Share Resources Across Multiple Projects In 1 Solution. Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, resources

"Using Visual Studio 2010"

In one project, I have setup some String resources.

- Right-Click on Properties under the project
- Select "Open"
- Select "Resources" tab
- Enter a Name
- Enter a Value

  Now I want to use those same String resources in another project of mine, that is located in the same solution.

I tried:

- Right clicking on the other project
- Select "Add"
- Select Add "Existing Item"
- Navigating to my Resources.Designer.cs file
- Selecting "Add As Link"

but it doesn't seem to work.

"Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change access modifier from `internal` to `public` in editor resources window (in resources tab). And Use this class from another project, just add reference to project with resources file and namespace in using. 
Also you can use `internal` resources with using Friend Assemblies http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0tke9fxk.aspx